# What the main reason to use stlport library in the code?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stlport

I saw someone use stlport in visual c++, but I think standard c++ library is included with visual c++ already? what's the advantage to use stlport? is stlport free?

Comment: http://stlport.sourceforge.net/FAQ.shtml#what

Answer (score 1):

Most likely either the code was written before visual c++ had a full implementation (for example in VC6) or the code is cross platform and the author wanted to make sure the same library was there on each platform. (That's not so much of an issue recently but even 2 or 3 years ago there were much more substantial differences from the standard in each implementation)